# Dependence of distribution standard deviation with subtraction of its mode from mean of normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

The following question might have relations to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77529/correlation-of-distribution-standard-deviation-with-subtraction-of-its-mean-from):

Given $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (mean and standard deviation) of normal distribution, find the set of all distributions with their $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ and $Mo_1$ (mode) that $\mu-Mo_1$ is any increasing function of $\sigma_1$.

If not a general result, at least providing a clue, references or examples of such distributions are very much appreciated. My question might be wrong or I could put it in a better way.

Comment: What kind of "nonlinear correlation" are you asking about?

Comment: Any nonlinear correlation that is positive. The context may be: when $\mu-Mo_1$ can be a measure of error in the second generally non-normal distribution (subscript #1)? I'd appreciate also an incomplete result, like for linear positive correlation.